# Powershell output formatting?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that scans for a specific folder in users `AppData` folder. If it finds the folder, it then returns the path to a txt file. So we can see the computer name and username where it was found.

I would like to be able to format the what is actually written to the text file, so it removes everything from the path except the Computer and User names.

Script:

```
foreach($computer in $computers){
    $BetterNet = "\\$computer\c$\users\*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\gjknjjomckknofjidppipffbpoekiipm"
    Get-ChildItem $BetterNet | ForEach-Object {
        $count++
        $betternetCount++
        write-host BetterNet found on: $computer
        Add-Content "\\SERVERNAME\PowershellScans\$date\$time\BetterNet.txt" $_`n
        write-host 
    }
}
```

The text files contain information like this

```
\\computer-11-1004S10\c$\users\turtle\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\gjknjjomckknofjidppipffbpoekiipm

\\computer-1004-24S\c$\users\camel\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\gjknjjomckknofjidppipffbpoekiipm

\\computer-1004-23S\c$\users\rabbit\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\gjknjjomckknofjidppipffbpoekiipm
```

Comment: Please show a specific example - by directly updating your question - of the information you want to write to the target file: is it, e.g., `\\computer-11-1004S10\c$\users\turtle`, or only, e.g.,  `computer-11-1004S10 turtle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have each line in a form of the string `$string_containing_path` then it is easy to split using split method and then add index(1) and (4) that you need:

```
$afterSplit = $string_containing_path.Split('\')

$stringThatYouNeed = $afterSplit[1] + " " + $afterSplit[4]
```

You can also use simple script that will fix your current logs:

```
$path_in = "C:\temp\list.txt"
$path_out= "C:\temp\output.txt"

$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($path_in)


 try {

    while($true){

        $line = $reader.ReadLine()

        if ($line -eq $null) { break }

        $line_after_split_method = $line.Split('\')

        $stringToOutput = $line_after_split_method[1] + " " +    $line_after_split_method[4] + "`r`n"

        add-content $path_out $stringToOutput 
    }

    add-content $path_out "End"

}

finally {

$reader.Close()

}
```

Comment: @Joe Clark is see someone changed the content of text file so each line starts \\ instead of \ so in this case please use indexes [2] and [5]  instead of [1] and [4]

Comment: Thank you. Had to figure out how to cast to a string. but got it working with this.

Answer (score 2):

If you split your loop into two `foreach` loops, one for computer and user directory it would be easier to output the name of the user directory.

```
$output = foreach($computer in $computers){

    $UserDirectories = Get-ChildItem "\\$computer\c$\users\" -Directory
    foreach ($Directory in $UserDirectories) {
        $BetterNet = Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $Directory.fullname "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\gjknjjomckknofjidppipffbpoekiipm")
        Add-Content "\\SERVERNAME\PowershellScans\$date\$time\BetterNet.txt" "$computer $($Directory.name)`r`n" 
        write-host BetterNet found on: $computer
        $BetterNet
    }
} 
$output.count
```